# Files not opening in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, mac, security, macos-catalina

All the files are saying:

> XXX is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Bin.

Most of the files are not opening in macOS Catalina 10.15.
I have tried to right click, disable the app protect. All are not working.

The zip and dmg file is coming from website, and Google Chrome installation media. Purely official. The PNG and pdf is created by the macOS itself. It even won't open.

[image: Zip file]

[image: DMG file]

[image: PNG file]

Comment: Having similar problem with 10.15.1:  Many files (e.g. Many PDFs, screen shots on the desktop, MS documents, etc. - but not all - generate error messages in Finder when I try to open by any of the normal means.  "The File <xxx> Could Not Be Opened".  I went to check my system log and it reports "Unable to read the file".  HOWEVER - the files actually will open in most cases.  For example, the screenshot and PDF files won't open in Preview but do open in Safari.  I ran Disk First Aid (no issues) and have reset permissions.  More will be revealed...

Comment: Aha.  My problem was that I had a VM in Parallels running an older MacOS at the time, and my volumes were shared.  I suspect (but haven't proven) that all my files were also opened by the other Finder.  It cleared up after a reboot without restarting Parallels.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Catalina but on newer OSes (Big Sur and Monterey) there may be a quarantine extended attribute set on files and apps. To remove this use:

```
sudo xattr -rc /path/to/file_or_app
```

But only do this if you are sure the file/app is trusted and safe.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Monterey 12.7.2 on my old late 2015 iMac Pro after updating to the latest version just now.

Following suggestions on other sites, I solved the problem by typing the following into Terminal (replace braces with the path):

```
hdiutil attach -verbose {path to .dmg file}
```

Oddly, this only worked when I included the `-verbose` flag.